# BackboneJS How to join an array of models and return as one View

Tags: backbone.js

How can I join an array of models into one and reurn the result?

I have the following:

```
var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    template: 'items',
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render); 
    },
    serialize: function() {
        return this.model.toJSON();
    }
});

View2 = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName  : 'ol',
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.on('sync', _.bind(this.render, this));
    },
    beforeRender: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
            self.insertView(new View1({model: item}))
        })          
    }
});

myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return 'path to json file here' 
    },
    parse: function(response){
        return response.data;
    }

});
```

I particularly refer to the

```
this.collection.each(function(item) {
    self.insertView(new View1({model: item}))
})
```

So far it works, but when I have a result of 100 items, it creates 100 views, and I want to avoid that, so how can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm afraid your intent isn't very clear.  If you have a hundred items and each needs to be treated uniquely, your choices are (a) have a hundred views each with its own handler, (b) have a hundred lightweight views proxying a single handler, (c) have a single view for a collection that knows how to associate something on-screen with its corresponding model (via an entry ID or data-attribute) and manipulate it as needed.

Comment: what is your concern with having 100 views?